# If-else statement with 4 QRadioButton

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I want make an if-else statement script with 4 radio buttons:

```
radioButton_1, radioButton_2, radioButton_3, radioButton_4
```

and here is my code:

```
def rb_check(self):
 rb_list=[radioButton_1, radioButton_2, radioButton_3, radioButton_4]
 for rb in rb_list:
    if radioButton_1.isChecked():
        print("You choose number 1")
    else radioButton_2.isChecked():
        print("You choose number 2")
    else radioButton_3.isChecked():
        print("You choose number 3")
    else radioButton_4.isChecked():
        print("You choose number 4")
```

Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1):

For what you are doing with the If statements you dont need the for loop as you are not making use of it.

You could do this:

```
def rb_check(self):
    rb_list=[radioButton_1, radioButton_2, radioButton_3, radioButton_4]
    for counter, rb in enumerate(rb_list):
        if rb.isChecked():
            print("You choose number {}".format(counter + 1))
```

Above code assumes that the buttons are in order though. If you have the buttons named with `setObjectName` function you could do:

```
def rb_check(self):
    rb_list=[radioButton_1, radioButton_2, radioButton_3, radioButton_4]
    for rb in rb_list:
        if rb.isChecked():
            print("You choose {}".format(rb.objectName()))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I want print output text into lineEdit, what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Have a look at [setText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) function. Change your print statements to `self.lineEdit.setText(string)`

Comment: If I want to make different output on radioButton_1 until radioButton_4?

Comment: Your best bet then is to handle the `toggled` event and use `self.sender()` to determine which button was toggled